# Matlab : Plot of entropy vs digitized code length

Tags: matlab, while-loop, do-while, entropy

[Tent Map][1] is a dynamical system that is discrete in time. Iterations of the map yields a time series.

The entropy of this system when discretized in 0/1 using a threshold = 0.5 is, H = log_2(2) = 0.69 approx. I want to obtain a graph with Y Axis as the entropy and X Axis as the Number of samples or the length of the time series. I have written a code for obatining the entropy by varying the length of the time series. The objective is to see at what length of the discretized time series, I get the entropy H. The code however, loops infinitely and never reaches the entropy value H. Can somebody please help in obtaining the graph? Thank you.

```
  [1]: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tent_map
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are saying that `lambda` must be EXACTLY equal to `log(2)`. When the entropy drops below `log(2)` it skips over this value (for instance instead of exactly log(2) maybe an iteration is 0.69309 which is less). Try replacing the line

```
while(lambda ~=H)
```

with

```
tol=0.01;
while(~(abs(lambda-H)<tol))
```

this will mean that it quits whenever `lambda` is close to `H` (with in the tolerance `tol`).

If your `tol` is too small (try 0.001) an iteration would jump over it again and you would be back to the problem you had before.

Comment: Just FYI, I tested this on my machine. Running your code with my changes does terminate as you want it to but I haven't verified that the results are physical. Happy coding/physics!

Comment: Thank you for your reply. When I excute the code corrected with your answer, sometimes code exits when j = 174 and when I again re-runit, then it takes several minutes in which case j is some million. What is the best practice in this case so that I can get a stable value of the counter value, j. Also, could you please show the plot command to get the graph? Thank you

Comment: ALso the first 2 values of the entropy array contains NaN most of the time i.e., entropy(1) = 1, entropy(2) = NaN, entropy(3) = NaN. Can you help in solving these problems, please?

Comment: Just run `plot(entropy)` to graph it.

Comment: You will need to call `clear all` at the beginning of the script to reset the `entropy` matrix. That is probably why it exits on j=174 sometimes and other times does not but I can't promise. I think why it doesn't work on a second run is because it is still using old `entropy` values that should have been cleared.

Comment: I have included the suggestions that you have given. But I cannot understand why NaN values are coming.