# Matlab : Help in entropy estimation of a disretized time series

Tags: matlab, entropy

This Question is in continuation to a previous one asked [Matlab : Plot of entropy vs digitized code length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37421738/matlab-plot-of-entropy-vs-digitized-code-length)

I want to calculate the entropy of a random variable that is discretized version (0/1) of a continuous random variable `x`. The random variable denotes the state of a nonlinear dynamical system called as the [Tent Map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tent_map). Iterations of the Tent Map yields a time series of length N.

The code should exit as soon as the entropy of the discretized time series becomes equal to the entropy of the dynamical system. It is known theoretically that the entropy of the system is log_2(2). The code exits but the frst 3 values of the entropy array are erroneous - `entropy(1) = 1, entropy(2) = NaN and entropy(3) = NaN`. I am scratching my head as to why this is happening and how I can get rid of it. Please help in correcting the code. THank you.

```
clear all


H = log(2)

threshold = 0.5;
x(1) = rand;
lambda(1) = 1;
entropy(1,1) = 1;
j=2;
tol=0.01;
while(~(abs(lambda-H)<tol))



    if x(j - 1) < 0.5        
        x(j) = 2 * x(j - 1);                        
    else  
        x(j) = 2 * (1 - x(j - 1));                    
    end



s = (x>=threshold); 
p_1 = sum(s==1)/length(s);
p_0 = sum(s==0)/length(s);
entropy(:,j) = -p_1*log2(p_1)-(1-p_1)*log2(1-p_1);
lambda = entropy(:,j);
j = j+1;
end
plot( entropy )
```

Comment: Hi there. Please do not delete, substantially modify, or vandalise your questions after an answer has come in. I don't see the purpose of your last edit, which removed so much of the question that it would be unclear/off-topic, so I have rolled it back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like one of your probabilities is zero. In that case, you'd be trying to calculate `0*log(0) = 0*-Inf = NaN`. The entropy should be zero in this case, so you you can just check for this condition explicitly.

Couple side notes: It looks like you're declaring `H=log(2)`, but your post says the entropy is log_2(2). `p_0` is always `1 - p_1`, so you don't have to count everything up again. Growing the arrays dynamically is inefficient because matlab has to re-copy the entire contents at each step. You can speed things up by pre-allocating them (only worth it if you're going to be running for many timesteps).

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I am declaring H = log(2) as it is the entropy of the system. I calculate the entropy of the biary time series nad quit the program when the entropy of time series (decraled by the entropy variable) = H. Is H = log(2) not equals to log base 2 (2) ? Also, is there a way of not having zero probabilities? The string is in 0's and 1's so I wonder how come the probability is coming zero.

Comment: After the first iteration through the loop, `s` will contain either a single one or a single zero, so the probability for the other value will be zero. It's not a big problem though, you can just use an if statement to check, and set the entropy to zero if so.