# Matlab : Confusion regarding unit of entropy to use in an example

Tags: matlab, signal-processing, entropy

[image: Tent Map Prediction]

**Figure 1.** Hypothesis plot. y axis: Mean entropy. x axis: Bits.

---

This Question is in continuation to a previous one asked [Matlab : Plot of entropy vs digitized code length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37421738/matlab-plot-of-entropy-vs-digitized-code-length)

I want to calculate the entropy of a random variable that is discretized version (0/1) of a continuous random variable `x`. The random variable denotes the state of a nonlinear dynamical system called as the [Tent Map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tent_map). Iterations of the Tent Map yields a time series of length `N`.

The code should exit as soon as the entropy of the discretized time series becomes equal to the entropy of the dynamical system. It is known theoretically that the entropy of the system, `H is log_e(2) or ln(2) = 0.69` approx. The objective of the code is to find number of iterations, `j` needed to produce the same entropy as the entropy of the system, `H`.

Problem 1:  My problem in when I calculate the entropy of the binary time series which is the information message, then should I be doing it in the same base as  H? OR Should I convert the value of H to bits because the information message is in 0/1 ? Both give different results i.e., different values of j.

Problem 2: It can happen that the probality of 0's or 1's can become zero so entropy correspondng to it can become infinity. To prevent this, I thought of putting a check using if-else. But, the loop

```
if entropy(:,j)==NaN
     entropy(:,j)=0;
 end
```

does not seem to be working. Shall be greateful for ideas and help to solve this problem. Thank you

**UPDATE :** I implemented the suggestions and answers to correct the code. However, my logic of solving was not proper earlier. In the revised code, I want to calculate the entropy for length of time series having bits 2,8,16,32. For each code length, entropy is calculated. Entropy calculation for each code length is repeated N times starting for each different initial condition of the dynamical system. This appraoch is adopted to check at which code length the entropy becomes 1. The nature of the plot of entropy vs bits should be increasing from zero and gradually reaching close to 1 after which it saturates - remains constant for all the remaining bits. I am unable to get this curve (Figure 1). Shall appreciate help in correcting where I am going wrong.

```
clear all

 H = 1  %in bits
 Bits = [2,8,16,32,64];
threshold = 0.5;
N=100;  %Number of runs of the experiment


for r = 1:length(Bits)


t = Bits(r)

for Runs = 1:N
    x(1)            = rand;

    for j = 2:t


        % Iterating over the Tent Map


        if x(j - 1) < 0.5
            x(j) = 2 * x(j - 1);
        else
            x(j) = 2 * (1 - x(j - 1));
        end % if
    end
    %Binarizing the output of the Tent Map
    s  = (x >=threshold);
    p1 = sum(s == 1 ) / length(s);  %calculating probaility of number of 1's
    p0 = 1 - p1;  % calculating probability of number of 0'1

    entropy(t) = -p1 * log2(p1) - (1 - p1) * log2(1 - p1); %calculating entropy in bits

    if isnan(entropy(t))
        entropy(t) = 0;
    end



    %disp(abs(lambda-H))



end


  Entropy_Run(Runs) =  entropy(t)
end
Entropy_Bits(r) = mean(Entropy_Run)
plot(Bits,Entropy_Bits)
```

Comment: Treshold is note defined in the script!? And what happened to `~(abs(lambda-H)<tol))` and `tol`?

Comment: Threshold = 0.5; sorry it somehow did not appear in the code

Comment: Hey, come join the chat below!

Comment: Chat: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113465/discussion-between-noumenal-and-skm

Comment: As per my remarks on your [substantial edits on your own question here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37474242), edits that remove swathes of code may be regarded as destructive unless they are justified by an edit remark or comment. It is probably best not to make them at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you just

```
function [mean_entropy, bits] = compute_entropy(bits, blocks, threshold, replicate)

    if replicate
        disp('Replication is ON');
    else
        disp('Replication is OFF');
    end

    %%
    % Populate random vector
    if replicate
        seed = 849;
        rng(seed);
    else
        rng('default');
    end

    rs = rand(blocks);


    %%
    % Get random
    trial_entropy = zeros(length(bits));

    for r = 1:length(rs)

        bit_entropy = zeros(length(bits), 1); % H

        % Traverse bit trials
        for b = 1:(length(bits)) % N

            tent_map = zeros(b, 1); %Preallocate for memory management

            %Initialize
            tent_map(1) = rs(r);

            for j = 2:b % j is the iterator, b is the current bit

                if tent_map(j - 1) < threshold
                    tent_map(j) = 2 * tent_map(j - 1);
                else
                    tent_map(j) = 2 * (1 - tent_map(j - 1));
                end % if
            end

            %Binarize the output of the Tent Map
            s  = find(tent_map >= threshold);
            p1 = sum(s == 1) / length(s);  %calculate probaility of number of 1's
            %p0 = 1 - p1;  % calculate probability of number of 0'1

            bit_entropy(b) = -p1 * log2(p1) - (1 - p1) * log2(1 - p1); %calculate entropy in bits

            if isnan(bit_entropy(b))
                bit_entropy(b) = 0;
            end

            %disp(abs(lambda-h))

        end

        trial_entropy(:, r) = bit_entropy;

        disp('Trial Statistics')
        data = get_summary(bit_entropy);
        disp('Mean')
        disp(data.mean);
        disp('SD')
        disp(data.sd);

    end

    % TO DO Compute the mean for each BIT index in trial_entropy
    mean_entropy = 0;

    disp('Overall Statistics')
    data = get_summary(trial_entropy);
    disp('Mean')
    disp(data.mean);
    disp('SD')
    disp(data.sd);

    %This is the wrong mean...
    mean_entropy = data.mean;

    function summary = get_summary(entropy)
        summary = struct('mean', mean(entropy), 'sd', std(entropy));
    end
end
```

and then you just have to

```
% Entropy Script
clear all

%% Settings
replicate = false; % = false % Use true for debugging only.
%H = 1;  %in bits
Bits = 2.^(1:6);
Threshold = 0.5;
%Tolerance = 0.001;
Blocks = 100;  %Number of runs of the experiment

%% Run
[mean_entropy, bits] = compute_entropy(Bits, Blocks, Threshold, replicate);

%What we want
%plot(bits, mean_entropy);

%What we have
plot(1:length(mean_entropy), mean_entropy);
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I used the condition (abs(lambda-H)>=tol) based on the answer given in my previous Question. Thank you for your suggestions as well. Which stackexchange site is better suited for Problem 1 so that it can be answered?

Comment: https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/converting-between-bits-nats-and-dits.521115/ tells that one can convert between the bases So, I applied the formula and converted entropy in nats inot bits, using x = log(2) (units in nats); H = log(x)*1.443 (unit in bits) ; %log2(e) = 1.443 and computed entropy using base 2, then the code does not converge !! This is because H =  -0.5289 bits now, negative entropy is causing the problem. Did I do some mistake in the formula?

Comment: This is way to advanced for me. I think you are in the right place to be asking questions about code. I think you could maybe get more attention if you improve the titles of your questions. You are not asking a question in the title. And you are not telling us why you need to compute entropy. If it is related to machine learning or statistics, Cross Validated could be a better stack. If it is related to information theory, try to understand the formula first by querying the Math stack. Plot as much as you can, lambda-H vs. j.

Comment: Thank you for your continued help. I would appreciate if you could take some time to go through the revised code.  I want to see what is the entropy for different length of the binary time series.Then, select the length for which entropy =1. But, running the code each time gives different result of the selection of length. This is   because of random nature of the dynamical system; the initial condition is not giving proper result as I want for entropy.So, I opted for a different logic explained in the next comment.

Comment: In the revised update,  Entropy is calculated for a particular length of the time series. I run the experiment N times for a particular length of the code for different initial conditions of the dynamical system. So, entropy for each time series will be an average entropy. Not sure, if this conveys the idea. But, I am having problem in the last array Entropy_Bits : it only stores the entropy value for the last code length. Shall appreciate if you can kindly help.

Comment: You should be able to figure out how to set the seed of the random function for debugging. If you can set the seed, the random function will return the same output and you would be able to study the parameters that you do not hold constant.

Comment: Do you need to accumulate the `Entropy_Bits` in an array?

Comment: Yes, I need an array in order to plot for bits vs its entropy

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113465/discussion-between-noumenal-and-skm).

Answer (score 1):

For problem 1, `H` and `entropy` can be in either nats or bits units, so long as they are both computed using the same units. In other words, you should use either `log` for both or `log2` for both. With the code sample you provided, `H` and `entropy` are correctly calculated using consistant nats units. If you prefer to work in units of bits, the conversion of `H` should give you `H = log(2)/log(2) = 1` (or using the conversion factor `1/log(2) ~ 1.443`, `H ~ 0.69 * 1.443 ~ 1`).

For problem 2, as @noumenal already pointed out you can check for NaN using [`isnan`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/isnan.html). Alternatively you could check if `p1` is within `(0,1)` (excluding 0 and 1) with:

```
if (p1 > 0 && p1 < 1)
    entropy(:,j) = -p1 * log(p1) - (1 - p1) * log(1 - p1); %calculating entropy  in natural base e
else
    entropy(:, j) = 0;
end
```